# Equality between 3 sets using 3 inclusions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be 3 sets. I want to show that $A=B=C$, can we use only three inclusions to do that ? For example we use $A \subset B\subset C\subset A$. Is this the only way to do this with three inclusions ? and can we do that with two inclusions ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, $A\supset B\supset C\supset A$ is the other way with three inclusions. Less would not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite the equality Statement in one formula you Need three inclusions. Alternative you can formulate the equality as: $A \subset B \subset A, B \subset C \subset B$. You have two inclusions, but 2 equations.